# How I can select random amount of rows based on varios criterias?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that has 3 main categories: `age`, `city` and `gender`.

The gender column is `boolean`.

The age category is in the following range:

```
['18-25','26-35','36-45','46-55','56-65','66-75','75+']
```

The city category has around 19 `cities`. So, for each city in category `'18-25'` and `'75+'` I would like to select 24 random rows for `females` and 20 for `males`.

For the rest of the `cities`, I would like to select 40 random `males` and 47 random `females`.

Is it possible to achieve this without having to run a specific query for each case?

I'm sorry the lack of code, but honestly I don't even know where or how to start :(

Comment: sample data please and expected result! so we can help :o)

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant. This is not easy to explain, but basically this has been like a thread of 3 posts where I was looking for answers. You definitely helped me with one of those questions. I was able to solve an important my problem with your `unnest` answer. I need to study more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows randomly and then just filter:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by city, age, gender order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where (age in ('18-25', '75+') and
       (gender = 'female' and seqnum <= 24 or
        gender = 'male' and seqnum <= 20
       )
      ) or 
      (age not in ('18-25', '75+') and
       (gender = 'female' and seqnum <= 47 or
        gender = 'male' and seqnum <= 40
       )
      )
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff. This, in combination with other answers of the threaded posts (3 posts, actually) was able to solve my problem. In order to get the other parts of the random selection, I need to perform the same query, change the range of `age` and the `seqnum` numbers and then perform an `union all` query, right?

Comment: @PedroPabloSeverinHonorato . . . I think I misunderstood the original question.  I modified the answer.  `Union all` is still not necessary . . . just complicated filtering logic.